# How to extract a struct values to a list in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a pipeline that extracts regular expression groups from a `polars` text column, and I want to display the text and matches in a `streamlit` `st.table`. Provided that the column containing the matches is a List[str] this works well with `streamlit`, but `polars` `extract_groups` returns a struct (understandable since regex groups can be named).

The code below works, but is there a way of doing this without using `map_elements`? In general, there could be 0, 1 or more match groups and I'd like to retain the output dtype of `list[str]` for `streamlit` compatibility.

```py
dataframe = pl.DataFrame([{"text":"ABC"}, {"text":"123"}])

regexp = r'^.*(\d+).*$'
dataframe = dataframe.with_columns(regexp_match=pl.col("text").str.extract_groups(regexp)).filter(pl.col("regexp_match").struct["1"].is_not_null())
dataframe.with_columns(
    regexp_match = pl.struct(["regexp_match"]).map_elements(lambda x: list(x['regexp_match'].values()), return_dtype=pl.List(str))
)
```

Comment: Your title is kind of an XY problem. Just use extract_all instead of extract_groups.

Comment: Not it's not, `extract_all` doesn't return match groups, it returns matches.

Comment: i.e. `extract_all` with `r'^.*?(\d+).*?$'` on "ABC 123 CDE" simply returns ["ABC 123 CDE"] rather than ["123"]

Comment: Change your regex to just (\d+) it's capturing everything because of .*

Comment: That's just an example for goodness sake. I have regexes that have capture groups that I want to display, Someone has provided a solution. XY is way of looking smart whilst not being useful imo.

Comment: Well everyone is entitled to their opinion. Cheers friend.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason a `.struct.to_list()` doesn't exist is because it only really makes sense if all values have the same type. (although, this is one of those cases)

You could get the number of groups in your pattern.

```py
>>> import re
>>>
>>> regexp = r"(\S+) (\S+)"
>>> re.compile(regexp).groups
2
```

And `.concat_list()` the range of each `.struct[idx]`

```py
df = pl.DataFrame([{"text":"ABC CDE"}, {"text":"123 345"}])

regexp = r"(\S+) (\S+)"

num_groups = re.compile(regexp).groups

regexp_match = pl.col("text").str.extract_groups(regexp)
groups = [regexp_match.struct[idx] for idx in range(num_groups)]

df.with_columns(regexp_match = pl.concat_list(groups))
```

```py
# shape: (2, 2)
# ┌─────────┬────────────────┐
# │ text    ┆ regexp_match   │
# │ ---     ┆ ---            │
# │ str     ┆ list[str]      │
# ╞═════════╪════════════════╡
# │ ABC CDE ┆ ["ABC", "CDE"] │
# │ 123 345 ┆ ["123", "345"] │
# └─────────┴────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':{'ab':[1,2,3], 'ac':[2,3,4]}, 'b':[3,4,5]})
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬─────┐
│ a         ┆ b   │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ struct[2] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ {1,2}     ┆ 3   │
│ {2,3}     ┆ 4   │
│ {3,4}     ┆ 5   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

You can convert the `a` column to a list of its values by `select`ing it, `unnest`ing it, then `select`ing all inside a `concat_list` like this:

```
df.with_columns(a=df.select('a').unnest('a').select(pl.concat_list(pl.all())).to_series())
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬─────┐
│ a         ┆ b   │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ [1, 2]    ┆ 3   │
│ [2, 3]    ┆ 4   │
│ [3, 4]    ┆ 5   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

You can make a function and patch it to `pl.Expr` instead:

```
pl.Expr.struct_to_list=lambda col: (
    col.map_batches(lambda x: (
    x.to_frame().unnest(x.name).select(pl.concat_list(pl.all())).to_series()
))
)
```

Because that is monkey patched, you can do this directly:

```
df.with_columns(pl.col('a').struct_to_list())
```

I'm not sure how to monkey-patch to the `struct` namespace though.